# Regex to strip leading zeros

Tags: c++, regex, string

I'm new to Regex in C++

Here is what I need:

> X000000043 -> X43
>
> B00030 -> B30

I'm using this regular expression

```
std::regex in("[A-H][[:d:]]");
```

I wonder is regex able to automatically strip off the leading zeros from the given String after checking with regex "in".

Or is Regex just a matching library and does not help to modify string?
Cheers.

Comment: Match `(0+)\d+` and replace first captured group by empty string

Comment: Let me note that `[A-H]` does not match `X`. What is your requirement? Have a look, [does it solve your problem](http://ideone.com/oJw8UP)? The regex will be `(^[A-Z])0*([[:d:]]*$)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `std::regex` also has a `regex_replace` method. It can modify strings based on a given pattern and a replacement pattern.

In your case, you can use *backreferences* to *captured substrings* (those substrings matched and captured with the help of *capturing groups*, i.e. subpatterns enclosed in unescaped parentheses).

So, in your case, you can use the following regex:

```
^([A-Z])0*([[:digit:]]*)$
```

The regex matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `([A-Z])` - any uppercase ASCII letter (that is captured into Group 1 and we'll be able to reference it with `$1` in the replacement pattern)
- `0*` - 0 or more zeros
- `([[:d:]]*)` - matches 0 or more any digits and places them into capturing group 2 (`$2` in the replacement pattern)
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tX1fP4/2), and [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/oJw8UP):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> strings;
    strings.push_back("X000000043");
    strings.push_back("B00030");
    std::regex in("^([A-Z])0*([[:d:]]*)$");
    for (size_t k = 0; k < strings.size(); k++)
    {
        std::cout << "Next string: " << strings[k] << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Replace result: " 
                     << std::regex_replace(strings[k], in, "$1$2") << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Next string: X000000043
Replace result: X43
Next string: B00030
Replace result: B30
```

**NOTE**: If you have these strings inside larger texts, replace `^` and `$` with a word boundary `\b`:

```
std::regex in(R"(\b([A-Z])0*([[:digit:]]*)\b)");
```

See this [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/sNfG93) and this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tX1fP4/3)

Comment: Just FYI: `[:digit:]` is the synonym of `[:d:]`, I used the expanded version in regex101 for demo purposes.

Comment: And FYI2: If you need to abstract from literals in `[A-Z]`, you can also use the `[:upper:]` POSIX character class to match an uppercase letter: [`std::regex in(R"(\b([[:upper:]])0*([[:d:]]*)\b)");`](http://ideone.com/zbKOPI).